# issue for war file from java springs project

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat7

I got a problem with generating a war file from java springs project by the command line I got below error:

[image]

Project structure :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To create the war file, you need to use **jar** tool of JDK. You need to use `-c` switch of the jar, to create the war file.

> jar cvf yourProjectname.war *

Your command is incorrect, the below one is the correct command.

```
jar -cvf yourProjectName.war *  
    /\
    ||
    ||
    ||
   This hyphen is required
```

hyphen **(-)** is missing in your command. Please add it.